# Laravel Limit Related Model

Tags: laravel-5

How to Limit Related Model from Parent Model in Laravel,

I have Category and News Model, I want to fetch all categories and each category with 3 latest news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this. You will get all categories  that as minimum one news model related

```
$news = Category::whereHas('news',function($query){
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(3);
})->get();
```